# Make TradingView chart interact/show an HTML element

Tags: html, pine-script

I'm new to Tradingview and Pine. Is it possible to show some HTML in a TradingView chart? I was thinking about something like this:

[Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH195.png)

I thought it would be cool to have some customised content in a TradingView chart, so we can make some cool interactions.

If it's not possible in Pine, then I guess it's not much of a Pine question (forgive me). What would be the correct approach to make something like this?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: Nope, you can't use the html syntax / formatting in pinescript.